# When using Google signin, can I redirect to the sign-in page directly, avoiding the need for a sign-in button?

Tags: google-oauth, google-identity

I am using "Sign-in for Google with Web" to let users sign into my app using their Google account. (as documented at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).

At the moment, there is a sign-in button rendered like this:

[image]

And then when the users clicks that button, they get to sign in like this:

[image]

Can I make it so that users go straight to this second screen? I can make changes on the backend if needed. Is it possible to just check the cookie on the backend and redirect straight to this sign-in page? The reason is that I am developing a simple internal tool and if a user is not signed in then I would like to send them straight to the sign-in screen, avoiding the need for the extra click.

Comment: That will be confusing to the user as they wouldnt know exactly what they are signing into. The Google Sign in flow is required for most Google products so it is helpful for the user to know exactly which Google feature or product they are using.